# Query to represent total value for significant dates

Tags: sql-server-2005

Given a table with the value of individual items in inventory for particular dates, how can I return summary data that reflects the total value at each unique date?

For example, given the following structure:

```
DECLARE @INVENTORY TABLE(
  EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
  ITEM INT NOT NULL,
  VALUE DECIMAL(6,2) NOT NULL
)
INSERT @INVENTORY VALUES ('2011-01-01', 1, 40.01)
INSERT @INVENTORY VALUES ('2011-01-01', 2, 35.01)
INSERT @INVENTORY VALUES ('2011-01-01', 3, 17.01)
INSERT @INVENTORY VALUES ('2011-02-01', 2, 50.01)
INSERT @INVENTORY VALUES ('2011-02-01', 3, 45.01)
INSERT @INVENTORY VALUES ('2011-03-01', 1, 10.01)
INSERT @INVENTORY VALUES ('2011-03-01', 4, 5.01)
```

What query can be used to result in the following?

```
EFFECTIVE_DATE  TOTAL_VALUE
2011-01-01      92.03
2011-02-01      135.03
2011-03-01      110.04
```

The challenge is that the inventory value would continue to be carried into subsequent dates. Notice that 2011-03-01 represents the sum of the most recent value for all four different items though only two of them have a record for that day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows value for items in every date:

```
SELECT 
   D.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
   I.ITEM, 
   COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM @INVENTORY II WHERE (II.ITEM = I.ITEM) AND (II.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= D.EFFECTIVE_DATE) ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC),0) VALUE
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EFFECTIVE_DATE FROM @INVENTORY) D
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM FROM @INVENTORY) I
```

This shows summary:

```
SELECT 
  EFFECTIVE_DATE,
  SUM(VALUE)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       D.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
       I.ITEM, 
       COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 VALUE FROM @INVENTORY II WHERE (II.ITEM = I.ITEM) AND (II.EFFECTIVE_DATE <= D.EFFECTIVE_DATE) ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE DESC),0) VALUE
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EFFECTIVE_DATE FROM @INVENTORY) D
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEM FROM @INVENTORY) I
) GROUPED_VALUES
GROUP BY EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Comment: Perfect! The first query will likely come in handy as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EFFECTIVE_DATE, SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL_VALUE
FROM @INVENTORY
GROUP BY EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Comment: Not quite that simple. I still need to include the amounts recorded from days prior if there is not necessarily a record for each item on each unique day.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this.  Please clarify, ideally by editing your question to show the desired numbers.

Comment: I've tried to explain it better, but for example your code would give me 15.02 on the last day, when it should be 110.04 (like my desired output shows). That would be 10.01 + 50.01 + 45.01 + 5.01 from each effective value of all items.

Comment: Why doesn't the 110.04 total include 2011-01-01? It sounds like you want a running total but I don't understand how you get your values.

Comment: @Nimrod, it would, but only if there isn't a more recent value for the same item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. It first select the max date for each Item and then join it with the original table to obtain the total Value.

```
;WITH Items as
(
select  Item,MAX(EFFECTIVE_DATE) Med
from    @INVENTORY
group by Item
)
select  sum(Value)
from    Items a inner join
        @INVENTORY b on a.Item=b.Item and a.Med=b.EFFECTIVE_DATE
```

Comment: That would work if only concerned with the most recent total. LukLed's answer shows the historical detail I'm looking for.